# Google Retail API Catalog Import Bug

Tags: google-cloud-recommendation

I'm using Google Retail API for Recommendations AI solution and for some reason, the import operation shows no problems, the items are visible but the dashboard with my summary data says 0 products in your catalog.

This is making my models return empty recommendations.

I have a scheduled operation to update my main catalog branch in a daily basis. The data source of the catalog is a BigQuery table using the retail api schema.

For some reason, a few days ago the number of items in the branch went to zero
[Retail API Catalog dashboard with number of items over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd3nl.png)

The items are visible in the table, but the scorecard says "0 products"

[Retail API Data Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MERLJ.png)

I did a test, purging the branch and uploading it again
[Catalog Activity Status Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkBEK.png)
You can see the activity status table shows 726 items purged and them imported again. But still, the items are visible and the dashboard says "0 products".

What might be going on and what can I do?